InfiniBand で UD (Unreliable Datagram) 通信が受信できない
InfiniBandを用いたRDMA通信のサンプルコードを書いています。
2つのサーバーでそれぞれ一つのプロセスを立てて、片方(Sender)からもう片方(Receiver)にデータを1回送るテストです。
Reliable Connection (RC) を使った場合は Sender から Receiver に正しく通信できているのですが、Unreliable Datagram (UD) モードを用いると、Receiver 側がデータを受け取れずに、受信待ちでハングします。
環境

Server

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6


Device

HCA: 1 x ConnectX-6 / server



再現例
使用したテストコード:
https://gist.github.com/nariaki3551/45294aaae0d12ab2189ae546231d9cd3
再現例（mpicxxコンパイラと, mpirunラウンチャーはOpenMPI を使用）
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nariaki3551/45294aaae0d12ab2189ae546231d9cd3/raw/64bae0f75b72ce67d7f5e3d701b9dc299de71005/test_ud.cpp
mpicxx -o test_ud test_ud.cpp -libverbs
mpirun -n 2 serverA:1,serverB:1 -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH $LD_LIBRARY_PATH -x PATH $PATH ./test_ud 

出力
Sender: (Rank 0) Starting MPI setup...
Receiver: (Rank 1) Starting MPI setup...
Sender: Using device mlx5_1
Receiver: Using device mlx5_2
Sender: Remote QP number: 57703, Remote LID: 32
Receiver: Remote QP number: 68825, Remote LID: 31
Sender: QP transitioned to INIT state
Sender: QP transitioned to RTR state
Sender: QP transitioned to RTS state
Receiver: QP transitioned to INIT state
Receiver: QP transitioned to RTR state
Receiver: QP transitioned to RTS state
Receiver: Waiting for a message...
Sender: Post sent request: Hello from RDMA Sender!, to qp_num 57703, lid 32

状況
Senderが ibv_post_send() しても Receiverがデータを受信していない。ibv_poll_cq() をポーリングしても完了通知が返ってこず、受信がブロック（待ち状態）のままです。
RC (Reliable Connection) を用いたテストコード では通信できており、物理的・論理的な接続不備が原因ではないと思います。UDならではの設定漏れが怪しいと考えているのですが、わからず。。。どこをどうチェックすればよいか、アドバイスをいただきたいです。
試したこと

Receiver側で ibv_post_recv() を呼び出してから、Sender側でibv_post_send()を呼び出し
Sender / Receiver の両方で QP を RTS に遷移させる
LID (receiver_lid) は非 0 を確認
送信時にwr.wr.ud.remote_qkey;は受信側のQPのPKEYと同一のものを設定

何かヒントをいただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いします！
